# Actuator using a BLDC motor simulation

Tags: motor, simulation, brushless-dc-motor, simulink, actuator

I need to represent an actuator which is using a BLDC motor in Simulink, for my Bachelor's Degree. I don't specialize in electrical engineering, but in mechanical engineering, so I'm at a loss here.
TL;DR: My BLDC motor driven actuator must be capable of moving an airplane's rudder in both directions (so the motor shaft should be able to spin both ways), the torque at the end of the driven shaft should be 11kNm, or the force 10kN (I have a 1.1m arm length). The other data I know is the input voltage for the motor (24 VDC). I have managed to create this rough model in Simulink which I will attach below. All I'm asking is for a correct simulation for what I am trying to achieve. The numerical values needed for each block, I will try to find out myself
PS: at the end of my simulation, there should have been a "force" block.

[image: my simulation]

Comment: Brushless motor torque is directly proportional to motor current.  Speed is directly proportional to motor voltage.  11KN-m is a very large amount of torque.  For high forces, consider a motor-driven pump and hydraulic actuator.

Comment: But with a reduction gearbox, as shown above, wouldn't the torque at the output shaft of the motor be much less than the output torque on the wheel and axle. Like, on the wheel and axle it has to be 11 kNm. So if I use an 11:1 reduction gearbox, the torque at the motor shaft should only be 1 kNm. Is this value still too much?

Comment: For comparison, an EV like a Tesla does not produce 1KNm.  Closer to half that number.

Comment: And have you gotten any ideas on a simulink model for this kind of actuator? DC motor with reduction gearbox and ballscrew to translate rotation into linear movement?

Comment: For a motor, I would use 90% efficiency.  Gearbox, 92% per 4:1 stage.  Power in * efficiency = power out.  Input power: Watts = volts * amps.  Output power: 1 watt = 9.55 Nm*RPM.